# prepend images on click - prepend just once then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend

```
$('button').click(function() {   
 $('.img-container').prepend('<img src="images/image.jpg">')
});
```

I have a one page design and a gallery section that becomes visible on click.
I do this by prepending the imgs. Here you can see how I add 1 image. The issue is that the more you click the more elements it creates.

Is there any way to make it create the element just once? Then somehow stop prepending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you handler is as simple as given then you can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) to register the handler so that the event handler will get executed only once

```
$('button').one('click', function() {   
 $('.img-container').prepend('<img src="images/image.jpg">')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/44s2jjcd/1/)

---

Another option is to check whether an image exists

```
$('.img-container').not(':has(.someimage)').prepend('<img class="someimage" src="images/image.jpg">')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/44s2jjcd/2/)

Comment: is it possible to prepend entire picture elements by the way?

Comment: I mean the HTML5 picture element and the entire source inside it. Thank you, your solutions works and I will accept your answer

Comment: great work done by @ArunPJohny Sir . I am beginner in Stackoverflow and inspired by your knowledge skill